# Guessing game creating new numbers when users enter each time

Tags: jquery

Okay, I have a problem that you guys might like to try and figure out. This program is supposed to say: "You guessed it right!" when the user enters in the correct number, but it seems that every time I guess, it is creating a new number for the person to figure out.

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hmzzg90c/

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chat-box").append("<div><br>What's your guess?</div>");
});

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {


    if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
        var guess = this.value;




        //do { 
        var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 100)) % 100 + 1;
            if (guess == number) {
                $("#chat-box").append("<div>" + guess + "</div>");
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>');
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">You guessed it!</div>');
            } else if (isNaN(guess)) {
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>')
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + ' is not a guess. Try again.</div>');
            }
            else if (guess == 0) {
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>')
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + ' is not a valid guess. Try again.</div>');
            } else if (guess < number) {
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + "</div>")
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + " is too small, guess again.</div>");
            } else if (guess > number) {
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + "</div>")
                $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + " is too big, guess again.</div>");
            } 
        }
    //} while (guess != number);
});
```

oh, I also have the do-while loof commented out since it breaks the code each time the page is run. How can I fix this?

Comment: Move your `number` declaration outside of the event listener. It's being recreated every time the function is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 100)) % 100 + 1;` is included in your event listener and will run every time the user submits a guess.

This makes the game really, really hard. :-)

Why not take advantage of a closure and do something like this:

```
var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 100)) % 100 + 1;

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
    var guess = this.value;

        if (guess == number) {
            $("#chat-box").append("<div>" + guess + "</div>");
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>');
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">You guessed it!</div>');
        } else if (isNaN(guess)) {
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>')
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + ' is not a guess. Try again.</div>');
        }
        else if (guess == 0) {
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>')
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + ' is not a valid guess. Try again.</div>');
        } else if (guess < number) {
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + "</div>")
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + " is too small, guess again.</div>");
        } else if (guess > number) {
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + "</div>")
            $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + " is too big, guess again.</div>");
        } 
    } 
});
```

Now, you'll only be computing that number once instead of once per guess.

Comment: Its the game that never ends, didn't you know? Haha, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

1. `number` must be declared outside of your event listener.
2. No `do-while` loop is required because the event listener will be fired every time the user presses down on a key.
3. You need to add the event listener *after* the page has rendered.

You can see this working in the **[updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsve/f0784xnr/2/)**. Or by expanding and executing the code snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chat-box").append("<div><br>What's your guess?</div>");

  var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 100)) % 100 + 1;

  $('#number').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
      var guess = this.value;
      if (guess == number) {
        $("#chat-box").append("<div>" + guess + "</div>");
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>');
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">You guessed it!</div>');
      } else if (isNaN(guess)) {
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>')
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + ' is not a guess. Try again.</div>');
      } else if (guess == 0) {
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + '</div>')
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + ' is not a valid guess. Try again.</div>');
      } else if (guess < number) {
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + "</div>")
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + " is too small, guess again.</div>");
      } else if (guess > number) {
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="human">' + guess + "</div>")
        $("#chat-box").append('<div class="comp">' + guess + " is too big, guess again.</div>");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #51a858;
}
#chat-box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
}
input#number {
  width: 320px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.human {
  background-color: #0026ff;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 70%;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.comp {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="chat-box">
    <input type="text" name="numberEntry" id="number">

  </div>
  <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, how do I make it so that whenever the user enters a guesses a decimal, it is not valid?

Comment: @HawkBlade124, ask another question on that. It's unproductive to discuss in the comments section as it is harder for future visitors to find the answer.